# Python Subprocess Pass Argument of Filename

Tags: python, cgi, subprocess

I know there is a better way to do this than subprocess.Popen but for the sake of time, thats what I am using. I have a script called save_input.cgi which saves a file to my linux box through a web app. When it has saved the file, I need it to pass that filename as an argument to another script. This is probably something simple I am missing, but here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get filename here.
fileitem = form['filename']

# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
  # strip leading path from file name to avoid 
  # directory traversal attacks
  fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename.replace("\\", "/" ))
  open('/tmp/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())

  message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
  subprocess.Popen(["python", "mod_check.py", '/tmp/' + fn])      

else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html>
<body>
   <p>%s</p>
</body>
</html>
""" % (message,)
```

Thoughts? Thanks a lot, I owe this community a lot haha.

*I just update it to include the subprocess in the if fileitem.filename block, but it does not seem to pass the filename and location to the script as an argument. To answer another one of the comments, yes this script does work if I manually enter "sudo python mod_check.py filename.txt"

Comment: Can you say why this doesn't work? From the looks of it, it should

Comment: Have you tested running `python mo_check <FILENAME>` on the command line? Does it do what you expect it to?

Comment: '/tmp/' + fn, just like when you created. Make sure to close the file descriptor first.

Comment: Also, you should probably move your subprocess call into the `if fileitem.filename` block so you only call it if the file was indeed uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple thing I overlooked. Resolved using jordanm's response. Added to the codeblock 'if fileitem.filename'